# Apache "Object Not Found!" on URL "/error/*"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, dictionary, uri

Hoping someone can help me determine where my problem lies. I have a whole PHP application architecture that is cobbled together. It has been working perfectly until I tried to create a URI map (in similar fashion to how the Slim Framework works). Here is a code sample (though using another architecture similar to CodeIgniter that I built in years past has the same issue):

```
class Err extends Base_Director {
    function __construct() {

        /* THIS WORKS EITHER WAY! */
        $this->get('/', function(){
            echo 'Error.';
        });

        /* THIS WORKS VIA '/err/404' BUT NOT WHEN CLASS IS 'error' ('/error/404') */
        $this->get('/404', function(){
            echo 'Numeric Error 404.';
        });

        /* THIS WORK VIA '/err/four' BUT NOT WHEN CLASS IS 'error' ('/error/four') */
        $this->get('/four', function(){
            echo 'Alphanumeric Error.';
        });

        $this->submit();
    }
}
```

I really think this is a problem with Apache but Googling and searching StackOverflow hasn't turned up anything that works. It seems like any URL using a $_GET variable (with '/error/*') returns Apache's "Object not found!" page. Content on page reads:

> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Yet every other URL value works perfectly fine.

Last time I attempted to solve this inconvenience I thought it might be a reserved keyword or something in Apache but I never dug through the web server files afraid that I might mess something up. If there is some code that you think I should include please let me know. Here is my `.htaccess` that I am using by the way:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ./index.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

**Update:**
I looked into the problem more to help narrow it down. "example.com/error/404" returns the "Object Not Found!" page as I have stated above and yet "example.com/Error/404" goes through fine.

**Update 2:**
Here is my httpd configuration:

```html
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
        #
        # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
        # or any combination of:
        #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
        #
        # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
        # doesn't give it to you.
        #
        # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
        # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
        # for more information.
        #
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    
        #
        # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
        # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
        #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
        #
        AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
        #
        # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
        #
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Didn't want to flood this post so one can find the rest of my httpd file on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/Hht9Dke6)

Comment: give an example of a URL you are trying to use that gets this error

Comment: Thanks Tomasz for the fixes to the format. Anything after "example.com/error/" gets this error (such as: "example.com/error/example" or "example.com/error/hello").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all you wrote by this, it will do the same, and may fix your trouble:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /error/(.*) /err/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

EDIT by Trevor:
I got the above working after editing `httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf` and commenting out `Alias /error/ "C:/xampp/apache/error/"`. One may also simply change the error redirect via the Alias as well. This appears to be a feature of Xampp and my addition to the solution may not work with other server "bundles".

Comment: Performed a fresh install of the latest version of xampp on a completely different computer and removed all of my php code except for `print_r($_GET)` and the .htaccess file you provided and ran into the same problem.

Comment: To have more informations, increase the log level : `LogLevel debug rewrite:trace8` for the rewrite logs to see if the rules are takeb and why it doesn't match & more logs in your httpd.conf instead of the line `LogLevel warn`

Comment: Ok changed the LogLevel. Here is a [link to the PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/NikN7f6G) of my error log. I don't think that is showing the correct information as it doesn't look like other rewrite logs so I'll get it sorted tomorrow. Too tired at the moment.

Comment: I don't see your server configuration (virtual host) it may be in other .conf file, and in your log i saw something really strange : `AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/xampp/htdocs/AcediaLabs Project Frame] does not exist`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97235/discussion-on-answer-by-froggiz-apache-object-not-found-on-url-error).